# How to return the each unique character per line in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, replace, find

I have a file (secret_message.txt) in the likes of:

```
Yap Cat Hat
Two Ants Like Two Ant Like Kids
Ants Like Cat Two
```

and I want to read each line individually and replace only one occurrence of:

```
Yap with Y
Cat with O
Hat with U
Two with T
Ants with A
Like with L
Kids with K
```

while ignoring repeated words, such that the output file reads:

```
YOU
TALK
ALOT
```

I plan to re-use the same secret code language for future messages, however, so I don't need to remake a new translation dictionary each time.

Any suggestions on how to do this most efficiently would be tremendously appreciated!

Below is what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob
import fileinput

filename = 'secret_message.txt'

with open(filename,'r') as f:
    f2 = f.read().split('\n')
    for line in f2:
        f3 = line.replace("Yap","Y",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Cat","O",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Hat","U",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Two","T",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Ants","A",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Like","L",1)
        f3 = line.replace("Kids","K",1)

with open('secret_answer.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f3)
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I don't suppose your secret code will be able to handle words that contain multiple instances of the same letter, like "happy."

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Actually that isn't a problem, I just need to be able to replace "happy" with a single letter of my choosing, like "U"

Comment: @cdonts Yep...unfortunately. Just posted it.

Comment: I don't mean as in "Yap Cat Happy," I mean how will your secret code spell out a phrase like "YOU TALK ALOT IN SECRET CODE"? The word "secret" has two E's.

Comment: ^ That's true, if it always ignores duplicate words during replacement then you can never build a word that has multiple same characters! (try using "mississippi" as a secret word :) )

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Ahh, I see...well, you've actually caught my secret! This is just a more interesting extension of what I am really trying to do with this code :D. That is, I will not need to return the same letter twice in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has a better solution, but if you build a list of potential keys before translating each line, then you can delete each key you use so that you ignore duplicates.

```
TRANSLATOR = {
    "Cat": "O",
    ...
}

def translate(line):
    keys = set(TRANSLATOR)
    secretStr = ""
    for word in line.split(" "):
        if word in keys:
            secretStr += TRANSLATOR[word]
            keys.remove(word)
    return secretStr
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction ShadowRanger, I didn't know that.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `str` as a variable name, as that masks the built-in.